# Apache wildcard subdomain endlessly loads page

Tags: apache-2.2, wildcard-subdomain

I'm on a Hostmonster VPS. I've pointed the A record *.example.com to my server's IP. Here's the main virtual host that's auto-generated by the server:

```
<VirtualHost 162.144.48.232:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com combined
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    ## User <USER> # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    UserDir enabled <USER>
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup <USER> <USER>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
            SuexecUserGroup <USER> <USER>
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RUidGid <USER> <USER>
    </IfModule>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/<USER>/public_html/cgi-bin/

</VirtualHost>
```

I can append to this in a separate file that gets included after this virtual host definition. I have the following:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/<USER>/public_html/subdomains/"
<Directory "/home/<USER>/public_html/subdomains/">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>


<VirtualHost 162.144.48.232:80>
    ServerAlias *.example.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/<USER>/public_html/subdomains/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I just put a test "index.html" inside `subdomains/test/`. It works fine when I go to example.com/subdomains/test/, but on trying test.example.com, the index.html file loads repeatedly. The same content keeps on repeating and the page never stops loading.

Any hints on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

It got fixed after I removed these two lines from the main VirtualHost:

```
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com combined
CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/example.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
```